# exclude a Realm model class

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have two Realm files configured in my app. I want to store my `Log` model to a separate file from the rest of my models. My problem is that I also see my `Log` model class in my default Realm file, which I don't want. How can I exclude a particular model class from a given Realm file?

I use the default configuration for my main Realm file, and I want to store the `Log` model only in another database file, but when I `default.realm` in the Realm Browser it also shows the `Log` model.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explicitly list the classes a given Realm can store via the [`objectTypes` property on `Realm.Configuration`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:vVC10RealmSwift5Realm13Configuration11objectTypesGSqGSaMCS_6Object__):

```
let configA = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: realmFileURL,
                                  objectTypes: [Dog.self, Owner.self])
let realmA = Realm(configuration: configA)


let configB = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: otherRealmFileURL,
                                  objectTypes: [Log.self])
let realmB = Realm(configuration: configB)
```

`realmA` can only store instances of `Dog` and `Owner`, while `realmB` can only store instance of `Log`.

Answer (score 3):

You can override this method in `unmanaged classes`

```
public class Log: Real.Object .... {
    ...
    ...
    public  override static func shouldIncludeInDefaultSchema() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

you can now create your realm with the default settings

```
   let realm = Realm()
```