# How to exclude a Realm model class from a specific Realm file in DB scheme?

Tags: java, android, realm

Realm version:

```
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"
```

I [found that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615171/2425851) I should add modules to `io.realm.RealmConfiguration`. So I made this:

```
RealmConfiguration.Builder builder = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .encryptionKey(/*my encryption key*/)
            .name("pay_card.realm");

        builder.addModule(new RPayCardRealmModule());

    return Realm.getInstance(builder.build());
```

RPayCardRealmModule.class

```
@RealmModule(library = true,classes = {
        RPayCard.class
})
public class RPayCardRealmModule {
}
```

RPayCard.class

```
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
@lombok.ToString(includeFieldNames = false)
@lombok.Builder
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
@lombok.NoArgsConstructor
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class RPayCard extends RealmObject {
    @io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey
    @io.realm.annotations.Required
    String id;

    private String billNumber;
    private String cardNumber;
    private String cardExpirationDate;
    private String cardType;
    private String cardHolderName;
    private boolean selected;

}
```

But when I look into the db file "pay_card.realm".

It looks like that. Why other classes are added to db scheme? How to exclude them?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`RealmModule` documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/RealmModule.html)

> Realms default behavior is to automatically create a `RealmModule` called `DefaultRealmModule` which contains all classes extending `RealmObject` in a project. This module is automatically known by Realm.

From [`builder.addModule()` documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#addModule-java.lang.Object-)

> FIXME: Temporary visible DEBUG method. Will add a module unconditionally. Adds a module to already defined modules.

From [`RealmConfiguration.Builder modules` documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#modules-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)

> Replaces the existing module(s) with one or more RealmModules. Using this method will replace the current schema for this Realm with the schema defined by the provided modules.
>   A reference to the default Realm module containing all Realm classes in the project (but not dependencies), can be found using Realm.getDefaultModule(). Combining the schema from the app project and a library dependency is thus done using the following code:
>   `builder.modules(Realm.getDefaultMode(), new MyLibraryModule());`

TLDR; You should use `RealmConfiguration.Builder.modules()` to clear modules list at first instead `builder.addModule(new RPayCardRealmModule())`